# WIX: How can the registry key be changed based on the OS on which the installer is running?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to set registry keys in following way

if OS is Vista then
   HKLM\MyKey1\MyValue=1 
else 
   HKLM\MyKey2\MyValue=1

I know how to set Registry keys in WIX but it seems the condition cannot be set on  element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically speaking, you should use two different Components to install those Registry keys since they are completely different paths.  Then you can Condition the Components with the VersionNT property.

Comment: This is exactly how we do it here too, we have some Vista specific registry keys that are in their own component. Works well, no problems :)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the correct way and works fine. Thanks. I was looking to somehow set a condition on Registry/RegistryValue elements or set a property value conditionally (IF(x) THEN property=a ELSE property=b) and use it as Key. But from various references, I figured out that its not possible.