# WiX will not add HKLM registry setting during Windows 7 install

Tags: installation, wix, registry, windows-7-x64

I have written a WiX installer that works perfectly with Windows XP, but when installing to a Windows 7 box I am running into difficulty with registry entries. I need to add an HKLM entry as well as the registry entry for the program to show in the start menu. Here is the code I am using for both types of entry:

```
<!-- Create the registry entries for the program -->
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="RegistryEntriesInst" Guid="...">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                 Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)"
          Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
      <RegistryValue
          Type="string"
          Name="installed"
          Value="true"
          KeyPath="yes"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="RegistryEntriesVer" Guid="...">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                 Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)"
          Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
      <RegistryValue
          Type="string"
          Name="version"
          Value="$(var.ProductVersion)"
          KeyPath="yes"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<!-- To add shortcuts to the start menu to run and uninstall the program -->
<DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
  <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="...">
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
              Name="$(var.ProductName)"
              Description="..."
              Target="[SERVERLOCATION]$(var.Project.TargetFileName)"
              WorkingDirectory="SERVERLOCATION"/>
    <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct"
                  Name="Uninstall $(var.ProductName)"
                  Description="..."
                  Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe"
                  Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="SERVERLOCATION" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue
        Root="HKCU"
        Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)"
        Name="installed"
        Type="integer"
        Value="1"
        KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

How can I fix this problem?

On a side note, the registry permissions are the same on the Windows XP and Windows 7 computers.

Comment: I was able to find where the Registry entries were going. They are actually being placed under the Wow6432Node. Is there a way to get it placed under the normal Software Registry Key rather than Software\Wow6432Node?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have figured out why this is happening.

With the WiX installer being compiled on a x86 platform, Windows 7 picked it up as the 32-bit installer with 32-bit registry keys. Windows 7 64-bit handles 32-bit registry entries by doing just what I saw happening.

The program was still registered; it was just not in the 64-bit portion of the registry. Compile it under a x64 platform while making the necessary changes to make it for a 64-bit system (ProgramFileFolder become ProgramFiles64Folder, etc.), and it will put things in the right place.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that you find the entry under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\[var.Manufacturer]\[var.ProductName]

Answer (score 20):

Thanks for basically solving this one for me!

I just wanted to add that you don't necessarily need to change everything to be x64 for this to work, only the component in question needs to be marked as x64.

```
<Component Id="MyShellExtension64.dll" Guid="..." Win64="yes">
  <Condition>VersionNT64</Condition>
  <File
    Name="MyShellExtension64.dll"
    Source="MyShellExtension64.dll"
    KeyPath="yes"/>
  <RegistryValue
    Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved"
    Name="{GUID}" Value="My Shell Extension" Type="string"/>
</Component>
```

Note the **Win64="yes"**, that is all that is required to write to the 64-bit area of the registry. The VersionNT64 condition is there so that this component will only be installed on an x64 system.

In my case this gives ICE80 warnings because I want to install a 64-bit component in the 32-bit ProgramFilesFolder. I'm happy to ignore these because because my main application isn't x64, only the shell extension is, and I don't want to put the shell extension in it's own special folder.

Comment: I do this, but it basically makes you put the registry settings twice -- once with win64=yes and condition VersionNT64 and the other with no and NOT VersionNT64 -- to avoid typing them twice you can use an include file, and then just include the same chunk twice -- and if the ICE80 warnings are bugging you, you can suppress them in the project property pages.

Answer (score 5):

There are some differences to how Windows 7 handles certain registry keys. Registry reflection was removed starting with Windows 7. I am not sure if this plays into what you're seeing here, but check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more on that.

Also, if you're working with a 64-bit version of Windows 7 you might be able to dig down into some specifics by referring to the [MSDN 64-bit Windows Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb427430%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Furthermore, if you need to have different registry keys installed into different locations based on the Windows flavour (XP, Vista, 7, etc.) then [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271580/wix-how-can-the-registry-key-be-changed-based-on-the-os-on-which-the-installer-i) also has an answer for you.

Comment: This was quite helpful and gave me a further understanding of the change from 32 to 64 bit systems.