# Writing in the x64 part of the registry with an otherwise x86 mai pack created in Wix

Tags: wix, registry, windows-7-x64, wix3.5

I'm writing an installer pack for a product using Wix, the whole thing is in x86, but now i need to add a key to the x64 part of the registry. I looked around and found [this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577367/923329) which I thought would solve my problem. But I'm getting a ICE80 error (not a warning) which tells me that I basically need to change my Package Platform attribute to x64.

I would however rather avoid that because as I mentioned it's only one registry key that needs to be in x64.

So my question is: Is there another way to resolve the ICE80 error or do I need to build two msi packages, one for x86 and one for x64.

Here is some of my code to further illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
        <Component Id="Foo" Guid="{GUID}" Win64="yes">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Compatibility\IniFiles">
      <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="Hello" Value="1"/>
    </RegistryKey>
    <Condition><![CDATA[VersionNT64]]></Condition>
  </Component>

  <Component Id="Bar" Guid="{GUID}">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Compatibility\IniFiles">
      <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="Hello" Value="1"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't support a 32-bit package writing to the 64-bit registry (or file system). A 64-bit package can write to both 32-bit and 64-bit portions.

Comment: So my only option is to make two installers, one 32 bit and another 64 bit?

Comment: This is how I solved it: I made a x64 bit console app that does the job for me which i then run during the installation, and then remove when i'm done. Not very pretty but it works, as it is only one key i need to write :)

Comment: No longer true - see the other comment below about using Win65=yes + suppression of ICE80

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it didn't work then. I am using Wix v10 and in my x86 WIX project, and adding `Win64="yes"`initially generated ICE80 error. Once I suppressed that warning (in Visual Studio, "Tool Settings" -> "Suppress specific validation:" column), I no longer get that error. When I ran the x86 installer on Windows 2012 R2, those x64 reg keys were created.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Win64="yes"` to the registry entry you want to put in the 64-bit in the registry..:) I have not included the condition in my own and it works perfectly with just the Win64 attribute.

Comment: I removed the condition and it is still giving me the same error :/ Do you have the x86 and the x64 components in the same package? Or maybe it has to do with the Wix version? I'm running 3.5

Comment: Are you getting any error if you take the win64 attribute out?

Comment: Is package platform attribute is set to x86?

Comment: Hi, sorry I am mistaken, I have two msi's being created one 32-bit and the other 64-bit. Apologies I got mixed up..:(

Comment: Why don't you use a custom action if it is only one key?

Comment: The problem with that is that my CustomAction.dll is also a in 32-bit.
This is how I solved it: I made a x64 bit console app that does the job for me which i then run during the installation, and then remove when i'm done!